# Find the address where a user entered this page in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to know user Find the address where a user entered this page in angular 8  .

for example : this user enter this page from `forgetpassword` or enter this page from `activationCode` i must show difrent form for user .

how can i do this ??

Comment: Can you please provide some more information?

Comment: Where do you want to use that info?

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand, but from what I could understand you would like to redirect the user to different views depending on if they used `/forgetpassword` or `/activationCode`?

If so, just define the routes in your app.router.ts file with the respective components for the front-end view.